# Hacking via Terminal Shell Script

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, cellular-data

Is there a shell script that you can use to hack cell phones with just their number from your macOS?

I ask because my phone was hacked with just the number and I am curious how it was done? This may be better suited for the information security group. However, since I am using Mac I thought I would ask in here.

Comment: Please could you expand your question to mention what aspect of your phone was hacked – was data accessed, settings changed, or maybe a specific app altered? Also what kind of phone are you using – Android, iOS, Windows, …? This extra information will help attract more informed answers.

Comment: @GrahamMiln seconded.

Comment: The whole thing: browser data reaching back a long time, text messages, and calls. I am not sure if they got facetime stuff.

Comment: Is this with an iPhone or Android phone? How specifically do you know the person accessed your data? Did the person show you? Were you on a shared wireless network? Without more detailed information, answers can only be opinions.

Comment: Not on the same network. And yes I personally know the person. I know for a fact that it is possible. I just need to figure out how it is done.

Comment: Same question on the Information Security site:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191820/cell-phone-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's concerning to hear that your phone was hacked.

> Is there a shell script that you can use to hack cell phones with just their number from your macOS

While there can be no definitive **yes**/**no** answer for your query, it can be assured that if you use an iPhone with a reasonably strong password, device passcode, Touch ID/Face ID authentication, two-step authentication (basically you follow reasonable [security advisory](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201303)) and change Apple ID password regularly, you should be in a much better/secure stand. Similar advise applies to users of macOS.

Objectively speaking, Apple's stand on user data privacy is pretty strong and generally, one stands a highly low chance of getting their device or data hacked.

Apple's Privacy page is worth referring to [here](https://www.apple.com/privacy/).

Comment: I like your answer, but I still feel like we are missing something here. There must be a program that exists that allows humans to do this. I have looked all over the place and can't find it. I don't like being in the dark on these kinds of things..

Comment: @CodyRutscher That's exactly the point. There could be an infinite number of bash scripts and another one which someone can write, exploiting unknown vulnerabilities in any of the various computer and communication systems involved. No one can ever definitively assume that one such script exist and proceed to find it!

Comment: I guess what I am saying is there must be one that is slightly more readily known then these "fly by nights". I guess if there was such a one, they would stop it or there would be some form of chaos.